# PCRE regular expression overlapping matches

Tags: php, regex

i have the following string

```
001110000100001100001
```

and this expression

```
/[1]....[1]/g
```

this makes two matches

[image: matches]

but i want it to also match the pattern between those both with lookbehind so to say, the overlapping 1

i have absolutely no clue, how can this work ? instead of 0 it can be any characters

Comment: `/(pattern)(.*?)\1/` Use this and get the second captured group value. No need of lookbehind.

Comment: If you need full matches, try [(?:.?(?<=1)....1)+](https://regex101.com/r/rN2uV2/1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common trick is to use capturing technique inside an unanchored positive lookahead. Use this regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
(?=(1....1))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM3zC1/1)

The [values are in `$matches[1]`](https://ideone.com/CAQHfz):

```
$re = "/(?=(1....1))/"; 
$str = "001110000100001100001"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See [lookahead reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

> Lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.
>
> **If you want to store the match of the regex inside a lookahead**, you have to **put capturing parentheses around the regex inside the lookahead**, like this: `(?=(regex))`.

Comment: thank you so much, i´ve already been playing arround with positive lookahead but didnt do right, this is working perfect and well explained

Comment: This is genius. One of the most clever things I've ever seen with a regex. Thanks! Saved me big-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using the `\K` feature (that refers to where the returned result begins) inside a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\K1)....1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmYH7D/1)

This way, you don't need to create a capture group, and since all characters are consumed (except the first that is in the lookbehind), the regex engine doesn't have to retry the pattern for the next five positions after a success.

```
$str = '001110000100001100001';

preg_match_all('~ (?<= \K 1 ) .... 1 ~x', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

[code](https://3v4l.org/cGfn9)

Note that if you are sure the second character is always a zero, using `0(?<=\K10)...1` is more performant because the pattern starts with a literal character and pcre is able to optimize it with a quick search of possible positions in the subject string.