# how to use php preg_match_all() with overlap matches

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I am trying (with no success) to get all possible matches with preg_match_all().

Any help would be greatly apreciated. Thank you in advance.
No related questions and answers clearly give a way to do that.

Here is a typical example :

the code is :

```
$str = "manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes";
$pattern = "/(.*) (son |sa |ses |un |une |des |du |le |les |la )(.*) dans (son |sa |ses |un |une |de la |des |du |la |le |les |l')(.*)/";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

the result (correct but incomplete for what I want) is :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes
        [1] => manger des pâtes à
        [2] => la 
        [3] => carbonara
        [4] => un
        [5] => restaurant de pâtes
    )
)
```

what is missing is the following match :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes
        [1] => manger
        [2] => des
        [3] => pâtes à la carbonara
        [4] => un
        [5] => restaurant de pâtes
    )
)
```

overall I would like to get :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes
        [1] => manger des pâtes à
        [2] => la
        [3] => carbonara
        [4] => un
        [5] => restaurant de pâtes
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes 
        [1] => manger
        [2] => des
        [3] => pâtes à la carbonara
        [4] => un
        [5] => restaurant de pâtes
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that building a more complicated pattern to get overlapping matches is a good idea for this case (as suggested by the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458195/pcre-regular-expression-overlapping-matches) invoked to close this question).

Here, all you have to do is just a little change to your original pattern and to use it twice, once with all quantifiers set to greedy and once with all quantifiers set to non-greedy.
It can be done easily with the U modifier that inverts the quantifiers behavior.

```
$str = "manger des pâtes à la carbonara dans un restaurant de pâtes";
$pattern = "/(.*) (son |sa |ses |un |une |des |du |le |les |la )(.*) dans (son |sa |ses |un |une |de la |des |du |la |le |les |l')(.*)\z/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches1) && preg_match($pattern.'U', $str, $matches2)) {
    $result = [$matches1, $matches2];
    print_r($result);
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/Ic7av)

I added the end of the string assertion `\z` to force the last quantifier to reach the end of the string when it is in non-greedy mode.